# Can't understand why classList.remove isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

It seems like my js function doesen't work properly.
Every time i remove the class "d-none" from an element, it becomes visible for like 1 second and then disappears again.

Function to make appear and disappear the element:

```js
function acquistaCrediti() {
  document.getElementById("form-pagamento").classList.remove("d-none");
}
```

Link that triggers the function:

```html
<a href="" class="title" id="acquista_crediti" onclick="acquistaCrediti()">
  ACQUISTA CREDITI
</a>
```

This is the element I want to make appear and disappear:

```html
<div class="d-none" id="form-pagamento">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
          <h3 class="text-center">DATI PAGAMENTO</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="form-group"> <label>NUMERO CARTA</label>
                <div class="input-group"> <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero Carta valido" required /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-credit-card"></span></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
              <div class="form-group"> <label><span class="hidden-xs">DATA DI SCADENZA</span></label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" required> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 pull-right">
              <div class="form-group"> <label>CODICE CV</label> <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="CVC" required maxlength="3" /> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="form-group"> <label>INTESTATARIO DELLA CARTA</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="NOME-COGNOME" required /> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="form-group"> <label>NUMERO DI CREDITI CHE SI DESIDERA ACQUISTARE</label>
                <input onchange="aggiornaPrezzo(this.value)" id="prezzo" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="NUMERO CREDITI" required /> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="form-group"> <label>PREZZO</label> <input disabled type="text" class="form-control"> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="row">
              <!--  <div class="col-xs-12"> <input type = "button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" onclick="compraCrediti(email)" value = "CONFERMA PAGAMENTO"></input> </div> -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to stop the code as soon as the element is made visible, but the page seams to reload automatically.

Comment: Avoid, stop using `<a>` if what you need is `<button>`. `a` is for navigating. Buttons are not.

Comment: Don't use HTML inline `on*` handlers. Use `addEventListener()` instead. JS should be in one place only, not disseminated in HTML.

Comment: If you really need to stick to `<a>` (bad) than use an `event.preventDefault()` (in order to... as already said: prevent browser navigating).

Comment: Clicking on a `<a href=''>` is going to reload the page, unless you specifically prevent that default action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad the comments have pointed out if you must use an `<a>` tag then you need to attach a click event listener to it rather than use the `onclick` attribute. Now you have access to the click Event itself and you can prevent the browser default action for an `<a>` tag, which is to navigate to another page. This is what your main issue was

```js
var acquistaCrediti = document.getElementById("acquista_crediti");
var formPagamento = document.getElementById("form-pagamento");

acquistaCrediti.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  formPagamento.classList.remove("d-none");
})
```

```css
.d-none{display:none;}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="acquista_crediti">
  ACQUISTA CREDITI
</a>

<div id="form-pagamento" class="d-none">
hidden content
</div>
```

Comment: @CODER but rather, use `<button type="button" id="acquista_crediti">ACQUISTA CREDITI</button>` instead. It's more markup and semantics appropriate, and there's no need to use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: true, but we don't know what @CODER's use case is. I agree, use `<button>` if you can, but if not then use the `preventDefault()`

Comment: Exactly. But was worth the explicit mention.